# Trigger a JScript webresource with a workflow on Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a request to if a case on CRM is created between 00:00 to 17:45 and not on weekends, to assign the case to a specific user.

I'm facing an issue that I can not trigger the Jscrip web resource to check the time, once the JS web resources only trigger onload or onsave the form.

Does anyone know how can I trigger that Js without having to open the case or when the case is created?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why a form script would not be sufficient? As Andrii Butenko answered, it is not possible to trigger functionality in a script/webresource from a workflow, but I'm wondering what would prevent you to implement the same functionality in a form script? Nevertheless, I would prefer creating a custom workflow step or plugin, but that depends on your skill set…

Comment: Javascript works when your browser open. So, what you want is not useful. You can try plugin or workflow.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to run JS from Workflow. The only solution for you is to implement the same functionality as your webresource has using WF/Custom Workflow Actions.

Comment: Hi Andrii thank you for your answer, putting your solution, do you know how can i set a compare time on a Workflow, for example created on between 00:00 and 17:45. thank you in advance

Comment: I would suggest to develop custom workflow activity that can do that.